# Como abrir o gerenciador de arquivos e ao clicar em uma foto, alterar a src de um ImageView?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um APP onde é possivel criar uma conta, então  eu quero saber como faço para ao clicar no ImageView, abrir a galeria do smartphone, e ao clicar em uma imagem, a src do ImagrView fosse alterada para a foto que o usuário selecionou.

Obrigado desde já!!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, defina um código padrão para identificar a `Intent`:

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 11;
```

Segundo, chame a `Intent` que será responsável por apresentar o usuário qual aplicativo ele quer abrir a galeria para escolher a imagem:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
getIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

Após colocar o código acima, você precisa sobescrever o `onActivityResult` da sua `Activity`, pois esse método receberá a imagem da galeria:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            // Nenhuma imagem selecionada...
            return;
         }

         InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
         Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
         Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
         suaImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
}
```

No código acima recebemos o conteúdo selecionado pelo usuário, primeiro de tudo testamos se está realmente vindo da sua chamada da galeria através da variável `PICK_PHOTO`, depois transformamos o `InputStream` recebido em um `Bitmap`, e de um `Bitmap` para um `Drawable` tornando possível utilizar no seu `ImageView`.

---

**Veja mais nos link's abaixo:**

[android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery)

[How to create a Drawable from a stream without resizing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361976/how-to-create-a-drawable-from-a-stream-without-resizing-it)